# Swift - Firestore Document references must have an even number of segments, but

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Xcode is giving me this error message:

> Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/hsiYfWgKz7MVOM77gMPkQYBHYJH2/wishlists has 3'

I have no idea why that error occurs because I thought there are 4 segments with this code:

```
let wishListName = self.popUpView.popUpTextField.text!

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(wishListName).setData(["name": wishListName]) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error saving Wishlist")
        }
    }
```

*Note:* The `document(wishListName)` does not exist before. I am trying to auto save it with the specific ID `wishListName`. Every help ist appreciated :)

Comment: This typically happens when `userID` or `wishListName` is empty, as you end up with only 3 segments in that case. You might want to log these values right before the line of code that throws an error.

Comment: that was actually it! Just a beginners mistake.. thanks

Comment: Since this is a common problem, I posted an answer in hopes folks find it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens when `userID` or `wishListName` is empty, as you end up with only 3 segments in that case.

If you log these values right before the line of code that throws an error, you can find out which one of the two is empty.